# How to get lastest tag of a branch - SVN

Tags: svn

Is there any way to get the latest tag that is created out of a branch in SVN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm, maybe. If, for example, we can assume that all tags are created in `/tags`, and you are looking for tags created from `/trunk`, then I think this will give you the latest tag:

```
svn log ^/tags -v | grep from./trunk -B 3 | head -n 4
```

If the repository is too large, you might want to test using limits for the `svn log` until you find a match, for example like this:

```
svn log ^/tags -v -l10 | grep from./trunk -B 3 | head -n 4
svn log ^/tags -v -l100 | grep from./trunk -B 3 | head -n 4
svn log ^/tags -v -l1000 | grep from./trunk -B 3 | head -n 4
```